# Problem installing RVAideMEmoire in R 3.6.3 Ubuntu 18.04 and "car" packages (curl, rio, FactormineR, alr4, rgl)

Tags: r

I have problems installing RVAideMemoire packages. It gives me errors saying "car" is not available. When I try to install "car", then I have the following errors
Can somebody help me? thanks a lot

```
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgl’
* removing ‘/home/anna/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/rgl’
ERROR: dependency ‘curl’ is not available for package ‘rio’
* removing ‘/home/anna/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/rio’
ERROR: dependency ‘rio’ is not available for package ‘car’
* removing ‘/home/anna/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/car’
ERROR: dependency ‘car’ is not available for package ‘alr4’
* removing ‘/home/anna/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/alr4’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmpet3m65/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("car", dep = T) :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("car", dep = T) :
  installation of package ‘rgl’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("car", dep = T) :
  installation of package ‘rio’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("car", dep = T) :
  installation of package ‘car’ had non-zero exit status
5: In install.packages("car", dep = T) :
  installation of package ‘alr4’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: You are on Ubuntu. Take advantage of the *binaries*: `sudo apt-get install r-cran-car` will pull in `car` and its dependencies.  Then try `RVAideMemoire`.

Comment: Done that, but it says Impossible to find package r-cran-car

Comment: It exists, see [this Ubuntu overview page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=r-cran-car) -- all the way down to xenial. Are you not on Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: However I get always the same output, unable to find package r-cran-r-car

Comment: You need a local helping hand. I can't tell from here -- maybe you did not run `sudo apt-get update` so your `apt` has no info, maybe it is something else.  _The package exists_ and package `RVAideMemoire` also generally installs fine:  https://cloud.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_RVAideMemoire.html   See if you can find someone nearby to walk you through things.

Comment: Or maybe you do not have `universe` enable in your `apt` settings.  However, R itself is in that too so ...